# Pine Script - How To Simplify code (request.security)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

i have code but error said

> "Script requests too many securities: 50. The limit is 40"

so please help me how to simplify this code ?

```
screener_func() =>
    ema12 = ta.ema(close,12)
    ema26 = ta.ema(close,26) 
    crossdown = ta.crossunder(expma12, expma26)
    crossup = ta.crossover(expma12, expma26)
    HitungBarEma = ta.barssince(crossdown or crossup)

array.push(EmaPair1, EmaPair1_1)  

[EmaPair1_1] = request.security(s01, '5', screener_func())  
[EmaPair1_2] = request.security(s01, '15', screener_func())  
[EmaPair1_3] = request.security(s01, '30', screener_func())  
[EmaPair1_4] = request.security(s01, '60', screener_func())  
[EmaPair1_5] = request.security(s01, '120', screener_func())  
[EmaPair1_6] = request.security(s01, '240', screener_func())  

[EmaPair2_1] = request.security(s02, '5', screener_func())  
[EmaPair2_2] = request.security(s02, '15', screener_func())  
[EmaPair2_3] = request.security(s02, '30', screener_func())  
[EmaPair2_4] = request.security(s02, '60', screener_func())  
[EmaPair2_5] = request.security(s02, '120', screener_func())  
[EmaPair2_6] = request.security(s02, '240', screener_func())  

[EmaPair3_1] = request.security(s03, '5', screener_func())  
[EmaPair3_2] = request.security(s03, '15', screener_func())  
[EmaPair3_3] = request.security(s03, '30', screener_func())  
[EmaPair3_4] = request.security(s03, '60', screener_func())  
[EmaPair3_5] = request.security(s03, '120', screener_func())  
[EmaPair3_6] = request.security(s03, '240', screener_func())  

[EmaPair4_1] = request.security(s04, '5', screener_func())  
[EmaPair4_2] = request.security(s04, '15', screener_func())  
[EmaPair4_3] = request.security(s04, '30', screener_func())  
[EmaPair4_4] = request.security(s04, '60', screener_func())  
[EmaPair4_5] = request.security(s04, '120', screener_func())  
[EmaPair4_6] = request.security(s04, '240', screener_func())  

[EmaPair5_1] = request.security(s05, '5', screener_func())  
[EmaPair5_2] = request.security(s05, '15', screener_func())  
[EmaPair5_3] = request.security(s05, '30', screener_func())  
[EmaPair5_4] = request.security(s05, '60', screener_func())  
[EmaPair5_5] = request.security(s05, '120', screener_func())  
[EmaPair5_6] = request.security(s05, '240', screener_func())  

[EmaPair6_1] = request.security(s06, '5', screener_func())  
[EmaPair6_2] = request.security(s06, '15', screener_func())  
[EmaPair6_3] = request.security(s06, '30', screener_func())  
[EmaPair6_4] = request.security(s06, '60', screener_func())  
[EmaPair6_5] = request.security(s06, '120', screener_func())  
[EmaPair6_6] = request.security(s06, '240', screener_func())
```

i need to simplify the code, so im not using request.security too much.

Answer (score 0):

You can true use request.security_lower_tf for examples with same timeframe

Comment: thank for the help, but i still cant use request.security_lower_tf , because i have function (screener) in that code 

error :Cannot call 'array.push' with argument 'value'='EmaPair1_1'. An argument of 'int[]' type was used but a 'series float' is expected